Databases for mtDNA with location/age
I'm doing some experiments on mtDNA, trying to infer samples' location/age based on the similarity among sequences. I was able to find good samples (with geographical coordinates and age range) for my model on https://amtdb.org/sample/, but other databases (e.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/, https://www.mitomap.org/) don't look to have the desired data available.
Would you know some database, website, project, etc. that has mtDNA sequences available along with location and/or age?
Thank you.

NCBI is accessible via their API, with Biopython Bio.Seq method SeqIO and SeqRecord using Genbank format results in objects with very rich features on each sample. Thus it should be possible to parse.

What species - are these human mtDNA samples? What do you mean by age? Given the low mutation rate of mitochondria, it's not going to change much over the course of a single person's life.
